# What fuel lines are recommended for a propane carburetor?

Tags: carburetor, propane

I've looked at a [propane carburetor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EP1L7QG) for a chevy small block engine to be used on a rock crawler so the engine wouldn't stall during inclines but I haven't seen any recommendation on what should be used for the fuel lines from the tank to the carb.  Besides rubber hoses that can break if a vehicle roles what can be used to deliver propane gas to a propane carburetor?

Comment: What about steel braided hose? I'd think any kind of line could potentially break if it gets hit hard enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Australia, our Automotive LPG hose standard is:

• AS/NZS 1869 class D

According to the following document, it appears that in the US propane hoses for automotive use needs to meet:

• NFPA 58, Liquefied Petroleum Gas Code, 11.6

• Referenced ASTM Piping and Tubing Standards

http://www.afdc.energy.gov/pdfs/48612.pdf

Edit: When searching for lines, make sure they meet these standards. You can get good steel braid rubber hoses all over the place.